# How to preserve the file permission in git?

Tags: database, django, git, permissions

I  encountered a problem which took me a long time to find a solution and still fail to get one.

The problem I had is 'DatabaseError: 'attempt to write a readonly database' when I tried to deploy my website through git to a Django hosting.

It seems like git will change the permission of my files, from 777 to 755.
But whenever I commit my project, this change will persist. However, I still need to write something into my database (sqlite database).

Does anyone  have a suggestion to configure my git to preserve the permission mode at each commit?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In short, you can't.

In longer, there are projects like etckeeper which can do it automatically, or you can write a small hook script which will fix up the permissions (which is probably how I'd do it).

For example, if you commit something this:

```
#!/bin/sh
chmod -R XXX file_or_directory/
```

To, eg, `scripts/fix_permissions/`, then run it as a [post-receive](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#post-receive) hook by simlinking it into `.git/hooks/post-receive` on the server.

Comment: Note that if you should probably using a post-receive hook to update the files your server is running from anyway, since running something directly out of a Git repository on a server is typically a Bad Idea.

Comment: That is very true. I like to keep my hooks in the repo, so they are versioned along with everything else, but that's because I work on small projects where all the developers have root access to the servers anyway… But it certainly does open up a potential security hole.