# How to deal with multiple Linux user files in Git

Tags: linux, git, file-permissions

I have a Git project that it's a bit special because the files in the tree are generated by two different users. Example:

```
# ls -la

drwxr-xr-x 13 ivan ivan  4096 2012-02-02 16:52 .
drwxrwxrwx 32 root root  4096 2012-01-28 21:37 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 ivan ivan  4096 2012-02-07 20:41 system
drwxr-xr-x  2 ivan ivan  4096 2012-02-07 20:41 compatibility
drwxr-xr-x 33 ivan ivan  4096 2011-12-08 18:13 resources
drwxr-xr-x  8 ivan ivan  4096 2012-02-07 20:41 .git
-rw-r--r--  1 ivan ivan   307 2012-02-02 16:52 .gitignore
-rw-r--r--  1 bulk bulk   700 2011-11-01 20:10 base.log
.....
```

Git is controled just by one user (ivan) but a daemon produces files assigned to *bulk* user. Everything was well whilst the daemon added new files, but when the daemon changed a file, git stopped working saying:

```
error: unable to unlink old 'base.log' (Permission denied)
```

I know the best option is to make the daemon run as *ivan* user, but that's technically difficult. The question is: is there any way to deal with this kind of situations in Git? I mean, I just want to do "git checkout branch" without having problems with user permissions.

Comment: do you need the base.log to be tracked in git? Usually log files are added to .gitignore (and it could make your problem disappear)

Comment: Well I need this and other logs. The problem is related to log files generated by the daemon, but I need these logs to be gitted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add you git user (ivan) to the 'bulk' group.

Debian:

```
sudo adduser ivan bulk   # and relogin
```

Others (FC, Redhat and similar?):

```
usermod -a -G bulk ivan
```

Everything should be fine. To have write access (i.e. so you can checkout, merge etc. you working tree), change permissions to allow the goup write access:

```
sudo chmod g+rw bulk.log
```

#### Alternatives:

- store archives (using cpio or tar, which are both capable of preserving permissions)
- possible combine with `bup`
- store permissions as text or scripts, see also [How to preserve the file permission in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163736/how-to-preserve-the-file-permission-in-git)

Comment: The problem is that is not only one log file, there are 18 and new ones could be created. With your solution (that is the best I have at the moment) I'll have to chmod each new log file.

Comment: @Ivan: what else do you expect? I could recommend you run as root :)

Comment: It could be a solution, but I don't know if it will add more problems later.

Comment: @Ivan rethink the goals. What are you using this for? Incremental log archiving has been implemented, see logrotate. Just move the rotated logs out of /var/log and change owners. If you need to track the original owners, store them in a text file/script

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a Git question, but for the sake of giving you an answer...

You're creating files in your repository, and then running a tool as a user that doesn't have full permissions for them. You have to fix one problem or the other: run Git as `bulk`, or create files that `ivan` can read and write to. Note that that doesn't necessarily mean owned by `ivan` - they could have `664` permissions, with an appropriate group.

The other solution, of course, would be to not track the files that you don't have permissions for. It's suspicious that you're tracking log files - that's not a normal use case, since things generated at runtime will be different depending on where you are, so there's no solid notion of what should be checked in - but I'll trust that you do actually need to do it.

So assuming that you do need to track those files, there is no way to make things work given your current setup. You can't write to files you don't have permission to write to.