# GIT pulls files down from remote with incorrect chmod

Tags: php, git, permissions, chmod

The files I have on my local repo are set mostly to 644 for normal php files.

When I make a change to any of these files and then pull them down on my production server the chmod of the file comes in with 664 instead.

Has anyone had this issue and what can be done to resolve it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163736/how-to-preserve-the-file-permission-in-git

Comment: This is interesting but why does this happen? I have worked in GIT hundreds of times and never had this issue where the repo has a file with 644 but when it is pulled down to one specific location it gets a permission of 664.